# PHP/MySQL form not posting data to database

Tags: php, mysql, validation

New to learning PHP form validation on same page. Please advise as to why my data might not be posting to the database. After filling out the form, it redirects to thank you page without sending data. Thanks!

http://pastebin.com/3T1W9Krx

Edit: Now that I know where my problem was, I have updated the Pastebin file to show the working code, which validates in the same page and checks the database for duplicate email addresses.

I was able to use Rick Kuipers suggestion below to find this error. I was trying to include a column for the primary key under VALUES, however I only needed the values for the INSERT keys, not ID or timestamp, as ID is set to auto-increment.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (last_name, first_name, age) 

VALUES (". 
                        PrepSQL($last_name) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($first_name) . ", " .
                        PrepSQL($age) . ")";

        mysql_query($sql);
        header("Location: volthankyou.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Q&A site, not fix-my-code site

Comment: I've worked really hard on this and just need some advice. Thanks though.

Comment: You are welcome to *ask* for the *advise*, not just throwing the code to fix

Comment: We are all working hard, just to let you know.

Comment: before `echo`ing 'Thank you', add var_dump($_POST) and send the result. After that, you should check why data is not being `insert`ed.

Comment: "Please advise as to why..." - not DO IT FER ME. Geez. You're obviously not working that hard Shrap.

Comment: This is just a weak excuse to cover "fix my code" meaning. A proper way would be posting here *relevant* code along with description of  your "hard working" on the problem.

Comment: I will do that and was planning to once I got the kinks resolved.  Thanks for actually offering something constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because of a problem with your query.

Try doing the following:

```
echo mysql_error($db);
//header("Location: volthankyou.php");
```

This should display the error if there is any.

Comment: AH! Got it- Column count doesn't equal...the problem is that the first column is the primary key, however I'm not sure how to set this under VALUES using the PrepSQL prefix and $value... trying a few things- thank you!

Comment: If the first column "id" is set to auto_increment you can just leave it out, it will fill itself in.

Comment: Thank you Rick- you helped me find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) is true or false for your insert. Otherwise, it will ALWAYS try and then, redirect to thankyou. And as spencercw points out, mysql_select_db could also be failing. Always check the result of such methods.

P.S.: always check server logs

Comment: `mysql_select_db` could also be failing.